# Meteor / JS Dates

Tags: date, time, meteor

So I am trying to make a timesheeting app in meteor, creating projects and adding time entries. Why? it was all I could think of as a test app.

But, I'm more used to dealing with PHP, in PHP I would just store a date field with a time length. Right now, I'm wondering what's the best wat to deal with dates in Meteor.

Do… I do the same thing where I store a parsed string of the date, or is it a date time object? How would you deal with dates? (I'm only 3 hours into Meteor)

Comment: options.createdAt = new Date() then you can use mongodb selector to select date between $lte $gte

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meteor also includes the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library which makes dealing with dates and times very easy. You get function to format and parse.

The best way to store your time is in a Date object. This is because in Mongo you will get the timestamp and its GMT deviation. Making the time TimeZone secure.

In order to manipulate and display times, use momentjs.

Comment: Thanks! This looks pretty sweet, I'll definitely be checking this out, and probably going this way.

Comment: bug with momentjs language pack: because of how Meteor loads files (lowest folder first) the language files of momentjs are not loaded. If you need to set the language in `moment.lang('fr')` you will need to copy the `fr.js` file to your public folder and load it in the main html

Answer (score 2):

This community hackpad with recommended methods and packages for storing and using dates is pretty useful:

https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Using-Dates-and-Times-qSQCGFc06gH

> The best way to represent dates on your collection documents is by directly using the Date object type.  You can store Date objects directly into collection documents.  If we are creating a document, we can generate a Date object as one of the properties supplied to the collection's `insert()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you store the time in epoch. It will make it a lot easier to sort and search. Normally getTime() gets the time since the epoch in miliseconds but you can divide by 1000 to get the time in seconds.[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

```
var d = new Date();
var seconds = d.getTime() / 1000;
```

To convert to the local date if you need it you can just

```
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCSeconds(seconds);
```