# Meteor JS: Date Range Query in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection that contains a `dateAcquired` attribute (which is from an XML API Feed the app is consuming).

I am trying to write a `.find()` query that will pull back all of the entries that are greater than or equal to 1 month ago from today.

The `dateAcquired` field date looks like: `"dateAcquired": "2014-03-28 06:08 AM"`.

How to do that query in mongodb?

Comment: That is a string and the reason why you are having problems. If you are regularly picking up the XML feed you need to convert to a date type before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil Lunn already stated, you should use timestamps for your dates in mongo.
More information to parse dates and so on [are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160956/meteor-js-dates)

If you use timestamps, then you may use something like this as find selector over you mongo collection:

{dateacquired:{$gte: date_from, $lte: date_to}}

You can calculate the dates with momentjs (recommended) or whatever.